# Why "type List does not take parameters" in Netbeans?

Tags: java, csv, netbeans

I tried this code but i'm getting error at `List<String[]>` (in netbeans)

Error: "type List does not take parameters"

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File("file.csv")));
List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
String[][] dataArr = new String[list.size()][];
dataArr = list.toArray(dataArr);
```

Please any one help solving this problem.

Comment: You are probably importing `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with NetBeans.

Comment: show imports used in this java-code

Comment: Thanx @Tunaki n sory i asked this with out seeing that "java.awt.list" import

Answer (score 6):

You're using [`java.awt.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) that doesn't take a parameter - that's why you're getting "type List does not take parameters" error, you should use [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead:

```
java.util.List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
```

Or simply import from the correct package.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using OpenCSV, the following works for me without an issue:

```
java.util.List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
```

As per the comment already, this almost certainly means you're importing the wrong List class (so check your imports at the top of the source file.) The most likely mixup is java.awt.List.

Answer (score -2):

Type ListIterator does not  take parameters
Means  your class name  and Interface ListIterator you are using in your program is same.